# echo Javascript Function to be held by Simple Pie function on Php not working

Tags: javascript, php, rss, simplepie

this is my first attempt to ask here, hoping for your kind attention =) so here it is, I'm making a simple news aggregator site that will shows random news base on the site viewer location `(COUNTRY)`. I'm using `geoplugin` and `javascript` to locate them and store their credentials in a variable that I will use to pass in php to generate specific `NEWS`, the problem is Simple Pie is not recognizing it, here's my code

```
 <?php
    $rssLocal = "<script> document.write('http://samplenews.org/' + geoplugin_countryCode().toLowerCase() + '/rss.xml') </script>";
    $rssLocalLink = "http://samplenews/ph/rss.xml";

    echo $rssLocal . ' ORIG <br />';
    echo $rssLocalLink;

    $feed = new SimplePie($rssLocal);
    $feed->set_feed_url($rssLocalLink);
    $feed->enable_cache(true);
    $feed->set_cache_location(storage_path().'/cache');
    $feed->set_cache_duration(60*60*12);
    $feed->set_output_encoding('utf-8');
    $feed->init();
 ?>
```

by the way, those two echo return the same result like this

---

`http://samplenews.org/ph/rss.xml ORIG`

---

`http://samplenews.org/ph/rss.xml`

Comment: $feed = new SimplePie($rssLocalLink); its working when I use to put this but this is just for comparison, this wont make the news dynamic

Comment: you cant mix php and js like that

Comment: you dont need js to get the users location

Comment: but I found it more easy and complex, but if thats the thing? will you give me some resources for this?